# How can I add a legend into a choropleth map?

Tags: python, legend, choropleth

I would like to add a legend to my choropleth map. I have used the geoplotlib library to plot, however, I don´t find too much information about this library in Internet. Therefore, it has been impossible to me to find a way to display the legend showing the maximum and minimum values according to the colour gradient. Do you know how could I do that?

```
import geoplotlib
from geoplotlib.colors import ColorMap
from geoplotlib.utils import BoundingBox
import json


#Define function get_color, returns the colour in which each county has to bee painted according to the number of TCAS RA (stored in pos variable) and the color map chosen (stored in the cmap variable).
def get_color(properties):
    key = str(int(properties['STATE'])) + properties['COUNTY']
    if key in pos5:
        return cmap.to_color(pos5.get(key), 2, 'lin')
    else:
        return [0, 0, 0, 0]

#Open and load pos2.json file.
with open ('C:\\Users\\W7\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\pos5.json') as fin:
    pos5 = json.load(fin)

#Select a color map
cmap = geoplotlib.colors.ColorMap('Reds', alpha=255, levels=10)

#We draw the polygons that size counties, painting them according to get_color
geoplotlib.geojson('C:\\Users\\W7\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.json',
                   fill=True,
                   color=get_color,
                   f_tooltip=lambda properties: properties['NAME'])

#We paint the borders of each polygon in black
geoplotlib.geojson('C:\\Users\\W7\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.json',
                   fill=False,
                   color=[0, 0, 0, 64])

#Open and read the file containing the airports in which VJ has experienced a TCAS RA.
data=geoplotlib.utils.read_csv("C:\\Users\\W7\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\seven.csv")

#Print points to the map
geoplotlib.dot(data,color='r',point_size=1.8)

#Print name of the airports
geoplotlib.labels(data,'name',color=[255,0,0,255],font_size=12,anchor_x='center')

#Focus on USA Visualization
geoplotlib.set_bbox(geoplotlib.utils.BoundingBox.USA)

#Show the map
geoplotlib.show()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest contact the author in the issue (https://github.com/andrea-cuttone/geoplotlib/issues/24). Somebody asked him about this feature. There is a ColorBar class but there is not documentation how to use it.